# Google Scripts Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I keep receiving this error message on google scripts, "missing ; before statement" on line 8. Can someone help me understand how I'm missing the semicolon from the code below?

```
function formula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var colC = sheet.getRange("C59:C").getValues();
  var colD = sheet.getRange("D59:D").getFormulas();
  for (var n in colC) {
    if (typeof(colC[n][0]) == 'object') {
      colD[n][0] = "=SUM(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(CONVERT(C59,LOWER(D59),"kg "))))";
    } else {
      colD[n][0] = "";
    }
 }
 sheet.getRange('F59:F').setFormulas(colD);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your second " on line 8 is making it expect a ; there not kg.

```
colD[n][0] = "=SUM(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(CONVERT(C59,LOWER(D59)," + kg + "))))";
```

Is what it should be I believe, my C# is a bit rusty, assuming kg is a variable, but if it's not I don't see why you're using those two extra "